# How do I insert text to scrolledtext widget in tkinter when using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am in the process of creating a GUI using tkinter to automate several laborious tasks.

The general simplified process is as follows:

1. Click a button in tkinter GUI to create a load of batch files from a single master batch file.
2. When a batch is created, insert a confirmation line into the scrolledtext widget in tkinter GUI.
3. Execute all batches in parallel (based on maximum number of available processors).
4. Add confirmation of batch start and finish times of each batch to the scrolledtext widget.

I can do Steps 1-3 no problem and can achieve Step 4 by printing batch start and finish times to the console; however, when I try to insert batch start and finish times to the scrolledtext widget I get the following error: "NameError: name 'run_text' is not defined"

I've trawled through various forums for a fix but have been unable to find anything that works so far. Since I can print to the console I thought of trying to write stdout to the scrolledtext widget but I feel like it isn't an ideal solution - and I haven't had any success so far anyway.

For reference I've included a simplified code below that simulates creating and running the batch files.

My python knowledge is basically derived from scouring the internet to find something that seems to do what I need, so any help of this topic would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import datetime
import time
import threading
import random

robo_batch = []


def create_batch():
    for i in range(100):
        if run_text.compare("end-1c", "==", "1.0"):
            run_text.insert(END, f'File number {i} copied to location')
        else:
            run_text.insert(END, f'\nFile number {i} copied to location')

        robo_batch.append(f'{i}.bat')
    threading.Thread(target=execute_batch).start()


def execute_batch():
    if multiprocessing.cpu_count() >= 60:
        max_logical_processors = 60
    else:
        max_logical_processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    with Pool(max_logical_processors) as pool:
        pool.map(task, robo_batch)


def task(identifier):
    print(f'{identifier}.bat started - {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}')
    
    ########## Line below is where the code falls over ##########
    # run_text.insert(END,f'\n{identifier}.bat started - {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}')

    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 9))

    print(f'{identifier}.bat finished - {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry('825x874')
    root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (500, 50))

    run_text = tkscrolled.ScrolledText(root, height=35, width=105, padx=10, pady=10, font='Arial 10')
    run_text.insert(1.0, "")
    run_text.tag_configure("left", justify="left")
    run_text.tag_add("left", 1.0, "end")
    run_text.place(x=14, y=50)

    run_bttn = tk.Button(root, text="Run batch", command=lambda: create_batch())

    run_bttn.place(x=650, y=9)

    root.update()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter widgets cannot be shared across processes.

Comment: Try using `ThreadPool` instead of `Pool`.

Comment: Yes! This! ThreadPool worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the help!